# Weird iconv_open behavior in Linux

Tags: c++, iconv, libiconv

In porting a big app from a Windows to Linux, I need to be able to convert between wide characters and multibyte characters. To do this, I have code that looks like this:

```
void IConv(const InType* begin, const InType* end, const char* inCode, OutType* outBegin,  OutType*& outEnd, const char* outCode)
{
    assert(end >= begin);
    assert(outEnd > outBegin);

    iconv_t cd = iconv_open(outCode, inCode);
    if (cd == reinterpret_cast<iconv_t>(-1))
        throw (InvalidLocale ());
 /* blah, blah, blah other code we never reach */
 }
```

That code is always throwing an exception. To debug this, I created a simpler version that uses the same parameters as the code that fails. Here's my test code

```
int main( void )
{

    const char outCode[] = ""; 
    const char inCode[] = "wchar_t";

    //Using wchar_t and "" means that iconv will just use the system locale settings.
    iconv_t cd = iconv_open(outCode, inCode); 
    if (cd == reinterpret_cast<iconv_t>(-1))
    {
        printf("iconv failed to use outCode %s and inCode %s\n",outCode, inCode);
        return 1;
    }

    iconv_close(cd);
    return 0;
}
```

Notice that the code is pretty much the same. But in my test code I never see a failure, whereas the IConv function always fails. The locale on the system is set via the LANG env variable, which in this case is always ISO-8859-1.

So, the question is, does anyone know of any particular behavior in iconv that might present itself in a big app, but not in a simple case?
Thank you

Comment: How is the problem code being linked (statically or dynamically)? And is the code running on the same machine it was built on? Is the code 32-bit or 64-bit? Is the OS install it's running on 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: The code that fails is linked statically into the main library of the app, which is then dynamically linked to the executable. The C-runtime is dynamically-linked. It's all 32-bit code cross-compiled for ARM in a 64-bit Windows machine using gcc 4.4.

Comment: Ahh, then the problem is likely that the target machine doesn't have the appropriate `iconv` libraries and indexes installed. See `/usr/lib[64]/gconv`

Comment: You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. I don't see the .so for my locale there. However I do see it for another locale I created with localedef. Do you know how those libraries get put there? Also, would you care to post it as an answer so that I can give you infinity answer points?

Comment: I am seeing the same problem, but in our case this is all happening on the same host (a CentOS 6.4 VM) and not due to cross-compilation. A simple test app that calls iconv_open("UTF-8", "WCHAR_T") returns a valid iconv_t, but is returning -1 on the same parameters when called from our big app on that same machine. Is there anything I should look at to see why iconv_open() would misbehave in our big app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely that the target machine doesn't have the appropriate iconv libraries and indexes installed. See `/usr/lib[64]/gconv`. The shared libraries are typically part of the `glibc` installation. Tools such as `localedef` can create them.